# VBA copy multiple sheets and paste to another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I tried to make a macro to go through every sheet and on each sheet, copy to the last row from B4:Y, and paste it to a sheet named "Total" starting from B4.

**For example:**

> I have 5 sheets named: a, b, c, d, e. My macro should copy and paste
>   50 rows from "a" at B4:Y54 and 60 rows from "b" at B55:Y115...and so
>   on.

I have tried looking up online but I can't get my code to work. Please help and thank you very much!

```
Sub TransferData()
    Dim LTot As Integer ' represents the line in the total tab
    Dim WsTot As Worksheet ' represents your sheet tab
    Dim i As Integer

    Set WsTot = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Total") 'declare your Total tab
    WsTot.Range("B4:Y10000").Clear ' clear the old data

    For i = 1 To 5 ' numbers of your tabs
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("" & i)
            .Range(.Cells(4, 2), .Cells(.Range("B10000").End(xlUp).Rows, 25)).Copy WsTot.Cells(LTot, 2)
            LTot = LTot + .Range("B10000").End(xlUp).Rows - 4
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Please ask a question and please post your code that you have tried so far.

Comment: What code I can use to generate above request? Thanks!

Comment: And what code have you tried so far? (This is not a code writing service.)

Comment: @Cassie.L Do you want us to give you the code, or do you want us to help you understand why your code doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will perform as you described in your question. Your code has a few issues in it and instead of building on it, I've rewritten the code in my own way.

```
Sub TransposeData()
    Dim wsList() As String, wsName As Variant, ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsTotal As Worksheet: Set wsTotal = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Total")
    Dim minRow As Long, maxRow As Long, nextRow As Long

    wsList = Split("a,b,c,d,e", ",")

    For Each wsName In wsList
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsName)
        maxRow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Select Case wsName
            Case "a"
                minRow = 4
            Case "b"
                minRow = 55
            Case "c"
                minRow = 116
            Case "d"
                minRow = 171
            Case "e"
                minRow = 181
        End Select

        nextRow = wsTotal.Range("B" & wsTotal.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        ws.Range("B" & minRow & ":Y" & maxRow).Copy wsTotal.Range("B" & nextRow)
    Next wsName
End Sub
```

**Below is the same code tailored to meet the OPs specific needs:**

```
Sub TransposeData()
    Dim wsList() As String, wsName As Variant, ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsTotal As Worksheet: Set wsTotal = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Total")
    Dim minRow As Long, maxRow As Long, nextRow As Long

    wsList = Split("Engineering Salary,Mailroom Salary,Reception Salary,D0 Salary,Dock Worker Salary", ",")

    For Each wsName In wsList
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsName)
        maxRow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Select Case wsName
            Case "Engineering Salary"
                minRow = 1
            Case "Mailroom Salary"
                minRow = 1
            Case "Reception Salary"
                minRow = 1
            Case "D0 Salary"
                minRow = 1
            Case "Dock Worker Salary"
                minRow = 1
        End Select

        nextRow = wsTotal.Range("B" & wsTotal.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        ws.Range("B" & minRow & ":Y" & maxRow).Copy 
        wsTotal.Range("B" & nextRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy
    Next wsName
End Sub
```

My worksheet tabs look like this:

[image]

Each of the 5 sheets have 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 in cell B1 respectively. After running the code, my "Totals" sheet looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi Tyeler, in every tabs there will be different number of rows and it will changes accordingly, it was just an example that I want the second tab paste after the first "50 rows from A"

Comment: Oh, so the range doesnt increase by a set amount per page?

Comment: No, it has different rows in every tabs

Comment: @Cassie.L Updated the code. Just change the min/maxRow to whatever is the min/max of the range on that worksheet

Comment: I have another question, what if the data changes everytime I open the workbook. Can the code copy the data to the last row by it self?

Comment: It already does. Unless you mean the data range on Sheet A changes...

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. Yes, number of rows in all the tabs change every time.

Comment: Okay, now you just select where the static minRow starts on each page, and the maxRow is dynamic to the last row.

Comment: Have I answered your question?

Comment: Hi Tyeler, when I run the button, I got Compile error : Object required on Set nextRow = (highlighted). Thank you for your help again

Comment: That's my fault, remove `Set`. I updated the code to reflect the change.

Comment: No problem, again, I got Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range on ' Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsName)

Comment: That's because your sheet names are different from the sheet names listed in the code. That one's on you as I don't know what your actual sheet names are.

Comment: Im so sorry for my noob. I have "Engineering Salary", "Mailroom Salary", "Reception Salary", "D0 Salary" and "Dock Worker Salary" and I have changed the "a,b,c,d,e", "," to the name above. Is there anything else I should change and add?

Comment: I've added a second snippet of code that reflects what your code should look like, tailored to your workbook.

Comment: Thank you. But I still getting the same error on the same line " Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsName)

Comment: Then you have the names wrong... I can't recreate your error, the code works for me. Double check your spelling, or add the code you're using to your question and a picture of your worksheet tab names, and I'll point out to you the difference.

Comment: I included pictures in my answer to maybe better help you...

Comment: I have exactly code as you, but is not working. Sorry that I couldn't take pic, Im using personal laptop and company's banned Stackoverflow. Question: Do you create it with a button?

Comment: Create what? You can assign the macro to a shape button on your worksheet if you want. I ran it from the module to test it. If you want to make sure you have it perfect, then double click the tab names (or sheet names) and copy them, then paste that into the code. There might be rouge spaces or some other type of mistake (like the letter O being a number 0). The problem isn't with the code itself, but with what you have defined as the sheet names. Also note, in the code where sheet names are listed, they are only separated by a comma, not a comma and space.

Comment: I copied it and it works!!!!!!!! I have another question, it seems like it copy from B, how can I edit it to copy from B4?

Comment: Thank you so much Tyeler, you have helped me alot! Thanks again!

Comment: To copy from B4, set `minRow = 4` for that sheets case.

Comment: IT WORKS PERFECTLY! How about paste as Values instead of formula. This would be the last request. Thanks again!

Comment: I updated the bottom code (the one tailored for you) to show the change. You remove the destination after `.Copy` and on a new line, put the destination and `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`. Also add the line `Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy` to remove the marching ants.

Comment: I should mention that doing it this way is going to convert numbers to string. If that breaks your worksheet, there's an alternate method we can use to do the same thing. Let me know if you can get it to work.

Comment: The code work perfectly! Thank yo so much for your help. I appreciate it very much! Thanks!!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Remember that you can get help like this any time you need, as long as you put a little effort into your question and show that you've at least tried a few things, even if they don't work. :)

Comment: Now I am understand a lil more..Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your total sheet needs to be called Total, it will loop through all the active sheets of the workbook

```
Option Explicit
Sub Outlier()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsc As Workbook

Set wsc = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.name)
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.name <> "Total" And Sheets("Total").Range("A1") = vbNullString Then
    ws.Range("A1:" & ws.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Total").Range("A1")
    ElseIf ws.name <> "Total" And Sheets("Total").Range("A1") <> vbNullString Then
    ws.Range("A1:" & ws.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Total").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

if you want to do specific columns then you would need to be clear on all the column names, however you would need to do something like

```
Set wsc = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.name)
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.name <> "Total" And Sheets("Total").Range("A1") = vbNullString Then
    ws.Range("B1:B" & ws.Range("B1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Total").Range("B1")
    ElseIf ws.name <> "Total" And Sheets("Total").Range("A1") <> vbNullString Then
    ws.Range("B1:B" & ws.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).oww).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Total").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If I have several tabs and I only want to copy specific tabs, "a,b,c,d,e", what should I change?

Comment: Instead of If ws.name <> "Total" use If ws.name = "NAME OF SHEET1 YOU WANT" AND ws.name = "NAME OF SHEET2 YOU WANT"  then, just keep on adding ands, but I would listen to Tyeler, it's a better answer

Comment: Thank you so much ! I will give it a try